# Can addPostFrameCallback get called after the widget is disposed?

Tags: flutter

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) of `addPostFrameCallback`, I see that

> Post-frame callbacks cannot be unregistered. They are called exactly
> once.

and so I wonder if `addPostFrameCallback` can be called after the widget is disposed since it cannot be unregistered?

Answer (score 2):

I think the `_postFrameCallback`'s callback will be called after the widget is disposed.

View the Flutter source code:

firstly, **Post-frame callbacks cannot be unregistered. They are called exactly once.** event registered after widget disposed, but still can't unregister.

secondly, when a new frame comes down, Flutter framework just check callback whether null, and then call the callback directly.

```
void handleBeginFrame(Duration? rawTimeStamp) {
  final List<FrameCallback> localPostFrameCallbacks =
      List<FrameCallback>.from(_postFrameCallbacks);
  _postFrameCallbacks.clear();
  for (final FrameCallback callback in localPostFrameCallbacks)
    _invokeFrameCallback(callback, _currentFrameTimeStamp!);
}

void _invokeFrameCallback(FrameCallback callback, Duration timeStamp, [ StackTrace? callbackStack ]) {
  assert(callback != null);
  callback(timeStamp);
}
```

So, the callback will be called.

But, you can't update the UI (setState) in the callback because widgets have already been disposed.

example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  bool isEnabled = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child:Listener(
          onPointerDown: (event) {
            setState(() {
              isEnabled = true;
            });
          },
          onPointerUp: (event) {
            setState(() {
              isEnabled = false;
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: isEnabled ? Test1() : Text("null"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test1State createState() => _Test1State();
}

class _Test1State extends State<Test1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("hahah");
  }

  _onFrameStart(Duration duration) {
    print("in _onFrameStart");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_onFrameStart);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```